# Multiselect with selected values

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select

I have a multiselect box and this belongs to a user or user access
   When I try to edit user, which has prevous access selected
The code to generate select is:

```
selected_access = [1,2,3]
<%= select_tag :user_access, options_from_collection_for_select(user_accesss, 'id', 'name', selected: selected_access),{ :multiple => true } %>
```

I get a multiselect with already selected items:

```
<select name="user_access[]" id="user_access" multiple="multiple" size="219">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">dashboard</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">profile</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">home</option>
    <option value="4">account</option>
    <option value="5">users</option>
    <option value="6">admin</option>
    <option value="7">contact</option>
</select>
```

When I try to select another set of items. I get a combination of both sets?
so when I submit my form after selecting account I get

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I expect to get only

```
[4]
```

Does anyone know what is going on?
I'm using Ruby on Rails to select the already selected item using

```
selected: [1,2,3]
```

Thanks

Comment: use the `options_for_select` form helper.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags

Comment: Please share more workable code such as the code for your view and controller for someone to help you. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: SO basically you have by default pre-selected items but when you select an additional item you'd like the default ones to unselect, leaving only the last one selected ??

Comment: Yes, That is the exact behaviour, I'm looking into